# Spring Boot 2.7.6: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jackson-databind

I know there have been a few duplicates of my question but none have resolved my issue so I'm creating a new question.

I have a spring boot app (v 2.7.6) with JDK17 which queries an ElasticSearch object. This object contains an Instant field which when being mapped to an Java object is causing the following error:

```
2022-12-07 00:43:14.442 ERROR 59384 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.GetResponse: jakarta.json.JsonException: Jackson exception (JSON path: _source) (line no=1, column no=280, offset=-1)] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling
 at [Source: (org.apache.http.nio.entity.ContentInputStream); line: 1, column: 279] (through reference chain: test.com.model.Project["createdDate"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1909) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.UnsupportedTypeDeserializer.deserialize(UnsupportedTypeDeserializer.java:48) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4706) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2879) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper$JacksonValueParser.deserialize(JacksonJsonpMapper.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:76) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMapperBase.deserialize(JsonpMapperBase.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer$1.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:99) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.NamedDeserializer.deserialize(NamedDeserializer.java:64) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer$FieldObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:78) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:192) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:148) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:76) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectBuilderDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectBuilderDeserializer.java:79) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.DelegatingDeserializer$SameType.deserialize(DelegatingDeserializer.java:43) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.DelegatingDeserializer$SameType.deserialize(DelegatingDeserializer.java:43) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.endpoints.EndpointWithResponseMapperAttr$1.deserialize(EndpointWithResponseMapperAttr.java:56) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.decodeResponse(RestClientTransport.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:295) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:148) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.get(ElasticsearchClient.java:831) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.get(ElasticsearchClient.java:847) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
...
.....
```

Originally I had no JacksonConfiguration so I would have thought the default jackson would have just worked.

After reading other stackoverflow posts I have tried creating a configuration class like so, but it has not resolved the issue:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullableModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfiguration(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaTimeModule dateTimeModule(){
        return new JavaTimeModule();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JsonNullableModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Here are also my dependancies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:8.5.2'
    implementation 'co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:8.5.1'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.17.6'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
//    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.0.3'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.13'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-security:1.6.13'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:1.6.13'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-core:1.6.13'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.13'

    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:1.2.8.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core")
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging', version: '1.2.8.RELEASE'

    implementation group: 'co.elastic.logging', name: 'logback-ecs-encoder', version: '1.3.2'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.12.142'

    implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
//    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.13.1'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.14.1'
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20201115'

    implementation group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.0.1'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre'

    implementation group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.12.0'
    implementation group: 'com.auth0', name: 'auth0', version: '1.34.1'
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"


    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.15'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things, add the dependency the error log talks about (which I see you did) and then create a objectmapper bean in your spring configs for your service to use. Please remove what you have in the config class above and simply it to just this one bean method:

```
@Bean
ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Games3D So I'm not sure what you mean by "a objectmapper bean in your spring configs"

Comment: Also, if I just remove everything in my Config class and just add what you have above I still get the same error. Could this be something todo with the elastic client I'm using? Thank you for the help btw

Comment: @MetaCoder can you please confirm that you are loading this objectMapper bean correctly into elastic search via debug? I think you should have all you need based on my above suggestion. The next thing I think might be happening is around this link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3262

Comment: Thanks @Games3D, so dumb question but how do I check this?

Comment: So when I do debug btw, I can see a JacksonMapper but I can't see what version etc

Answer (score 0):

From you logs you can see that ES is using `JacksonJsonpMapper` for parsing and it is not using object mapper configured by Spring. Also, you will lose autoconfiguration for `ObjectMapper` if you define it as a bean yourself.

Define `JacksonJsonpMapper` yourself with autoconfigured `ObjectMapper`
and add this additional custom converters for ES

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    /**
     * Support for Java date and time API.
     * @return the corresponding Jackson module.
     */
    @Bean
    public JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule() {
        return new JavaTimeModule();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jdk8Module jdk8TimeModule() {
        return new Jdk8Module();
    }

}


@Configuration
public class ESConfig extends ElasticsearchConfigurationSupport {


    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonpMapper jacksonJsonpMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JacksonJsonpMapper(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public ElasticsearchCustomConversions elasticsearchCustomConversions() {
        return new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(
                List.of(
                        new ZonedDateTimeWritingConverter(),
                        new ZonedDateTimeReadingConverter(),
                        new InstantWritingConverter(),
                        new InstantReadingConverter(),
                        new LocalDateWritingConverter(),
                        new LocalDateReadingConverter()
                )
        );
    }

    @WritingConverter
    static class ZonedDateTimeWritingConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, String> {

        @Override
        public String convert(ZonedDateTime source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return source.toInstant().toString();
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    static class ZonedDateTimeReadingConverter implements Converter<String, ZonedDateTime> {

        @Override
        public ZonedDateTime convert(String source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return Instant.parse(source).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
    }

    @WritingConverter
    static class InstantWritingConverter implements Converter<Instant, String> {

        @Override
        public String convert(Instant source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return source.toString();
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    static class InstantReadingConverter implements Converter<String, Instant> {

        @Override
        public Instant convert(String source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return Instant.parse(source);
        }
    }

    @WritingConverter
    static class LocalDateWritingConverter implements Converter<LocalDate, String> {

        @Override
        public String convert(LocalDate source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return source.toString();
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    static class LocalDateReadingConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

        @Override
        public LocalDate convert(String source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return LocalDate.parse(source);
        }
    }

}
```